# How can I clear "asset static" or "Asset index.html" this from my terminal window when running react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, macos, command-line

I've been working on a react project and have used git for version control - sometimes I work on it using my windows pc and sometimes using my Macbook Pro. I was wondering if anyone knew how to clear the following garbage from the command line when I run the react app.

> asset static/js/bundle.js 1.43 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related
> asset asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted] asset asset-manifest.json
> 190 bytes [emitted] cached modules 1.33 MiB [cached] 89 modules
> runtime modules 28.1 KiB 13 modules ./src/App.js 3.95 KiB [built]
> [code generated] webpack 5.65.0 compiled successfully in 1818 ms

[Screenshot of terminal window can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAu2z.png)